# Is it possible to implement a tcp serverSocket in a java web application on glassfish?

Tags: java, tcp, glassfish, serversocket

I would like to know if it is possible to open a tcp serversocket within a java web application, i've tried, but it always fails to bind the socket to an address and port.

I was trying to open it within the application context listner, in a strait forward manner, just created an instance and gave it an ip address and port.

I've tried several combinations of ip addresses and ports, and nothing worked,maybe it's impossible to opened that kind of connnection from within the glassfish serer, but I haven't seen nothing to tell me that.

Comment: You need to show some code. Are you spawning a thread to wait for incoming connections?

Comment: Yes i am, but that doesn't matter, it doesn't even make it that far, it fails at the serversocket instantiation, like I described in the question. Glassfish sends a error saying that the socket can't bind to the address. The ports that I tried to bind weren't in use, but it still failed, my believe is that either glassfish doesn't support running server sockets, or i need to configure something to allow them to run. If i don't provide a port to bind, it can't automatically create one either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible, but it's forbidden by the specification. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html for further details. You shouldn't even start a new thread from EJB or web application.

For this purpose, the only allowed way is to open the server socket using JCA resource adapter. The communication with your EJB is then performed through message-driven beans.

Yes, it sounds complicated. A good starting point is http://code.google.com/p/jca-sockets/ . I have implemented a CIFS server using this approach and it works perfectly.

Another complication could be, that the port you are trying to bind is occupied, or the GlassFish is not allowed to bind to it. For example on Linux, only root user could bind to "privileged" ports (<1024).

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful anwer